# Electron navbar only dragable on top and drag does not works when scrolled

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, electron, tailwind-css

upon more debugging i came to know that click is registered below the navbar on the card thats why the drag don't work when scrolled but it works when on top,

the stack i am using is react, electron, tailwind-css

here is the screen shots of the mess up ....

can't drag the window here
[image: can't drag the window]

can drag the window here
[image: can drag the window]

now some code ....

> **Navbar**

```
function Navbar({ label }) {
  return (
    <div className="nav navbar bg-base-100 text-secondary sticky top-0 z-20 enabledrag  ">
      <div>
        {label}
        <a className="btn btn-ghost normal-case text-xl disabledrag">example</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Navbar
```

> **Pagecontent**

```
function Card() {
  return (
    <div className="card rounded-lg bg-base-100 shadow-xl disabledrag ">
      <figure>
        <img
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525966222134-fcfa99b8ae77?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8c2hvZXN8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
          alt="Shoes"
          className="w-96 h-60 rounded-lg "
        />
      </figure>
    </div>
  )
}

function Pagecontent() {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 m-4 justify-items-center grid-flow-row-dense z-10 disabledrag ">
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
      <Card />
    </div>
  )
}
export default Pagecontent
```

> ***Cssfile***

```
body {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.enabledrag {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.disabledrag {
  -webkit-app-region: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px; /* for vertical scrollbars */
  height: 12px; /* for horizontal scrollbars */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgb(55, 58, 80);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(58, 84, 199, 0.89);

  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

> ***browser window***

```
 // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 670,

    minWidth: 1300,
    minHeight: 700,


    // settings here boi
    frame: false,
    titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: '#2f3241',
      symbolColor: '#74b1be',
      height: 20,
      width: 40
    },

    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  })
```

according to electron docs i should be able to drag the window
in that cause i believe click is going-through which it should not be ...

guess making the navbar sticky caused this much headache
any kinda help will be appreciated
hopefully tomorrow someone replies ...

Comment: I think it's the zindex issue. try settings `z-[999]` and test it. Again it depends on the layout. Or simply you can replace `sticky` with `fixed z-[999]` it should work

Comment: i even tried this one but in the end i ended up changing the layout of the app, thanks though